# Why have menu links to extensions eg DataViz, CiviDiscount, LogViewer now give the civi home page

Tags: extension, cache

After upgrading to 5.3.1 and clearing out templates_c and doing two drush cc all we are still finding sites where then menu link to eg CiviDiscount or LogViewer just show the civi home page

What is the long term fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

We know one quick fix is to resave the Directory page civicrm/admin/setting/path?reset=1

(Note: we tested with making a minor change then saving but it may work with just using Save)

Looking for other broken sites so I can next test
 civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1